# How to find an average without the group by clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data which I get from a query:

```
SELECT sid, cnum, dept, grade 
from offering 
   natural join took 
where cnum >= 300;
```

```
  sid  | cnum | dept | grade
-------+------+------+-------
 99132 |  343 | CSC  |    79
 98000 |  343 | CSC  |    82
 98000 |  320 | ENV  |    79
```

What I want is the average grade `(79 + 82 + 79)/3 = 80`.

I was thinking about doing select `avg(grade)` and essentially grouping by "nothing", since we just want the overall result.

However when using an aggregate function, I must provide a `group by` statement.

So the question becomes how can I find the average across all grades, ignoring the rest of the columns?

I tried saving the query as a `view`, and then it worked, but I am not sure why.

```
CREATE VIEW grades3 as SELECT sid, cnum ...;
SELECT avg(grade) from grades3;

             avg
    ---------------------
     80.0000000000000000
    (1 row)
```

So in summary, my question is why can't I just take the average directly. Why must I first save it as a view, and then take it?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a `GROUP BY`.  You can do:

```
SELECT avg(grade) 
FROM offering NATURAL JOIN
     took 
WHERE cnum >= 300;
```

With no `GROUP BY` an aggregation query always returns exactly one row -- even when no rows match.  If there are no matching rows, the value is `NULL`.

I strongly *discourage* you from using an `NATURAL JOIN`.  I consider the implementation `NATURAL JOIN` in the SQL standard to be an abomination, because it does not take into account properly declared foreign key relationships.

Instead, it simply relies on columns having the same name.  This means that your queries are prone to error, because you don't know what the columns are in the table.  They are difficult for you (at a later time) or for someone else to understand and modify, because the `JOIN` keys are not obvious.  Adding columns to tables -- which is usually pretty safe -- can break existing queries.

Instead, you can use `USING` or `ON` to explicitly show the `JOIN` keys:

```
SELECT avg(grade) 
FROM offering JOIN
     took 
     USING ( . . . )  -- join columns here
WHERE cnum >= 300;
```

You should also qualify all column references and use table aliases:

```
SELECT avg(?.grade)
FROM offering o JOIN
     took t
     USING ( . . . )  -- join columns here
WHERE ?.cnum >= 300;
```

The `?` is the alias of the source table for the column, either `o` or `t` in this case.

Comment: I wonder why nobody ever came up with a "NATURAL" `JOIN` that takes into account foreign key constraints?